# Writing lim sup and lim inf alternative form

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

> (1) Write the set $\bigcap_\alpha A_{\alpha}$ and 
>   $\bigcup_\alpha A_{\alpha}$ in simple form where $A=(0,1)$ and 
>   $A_{\alpha}=\{x\in\Bbb R \mid \alpha^2< x < \alpha \}$
>
> (2) Write the set   $\bigcap\limits^\infty_{n=1}$ $\bigl(\bigcup\limits^\infty_{k=n}A_{k}\bigr)$ and $\bigcup\limits^\infty_{n=1}\bigl(\bigcap\limits^\infty_{k=n}A_{k}\bigr)$ in simple form where $A_{k}=[k,k+1]$

For part (1) do I just have to write $A_\alpha=\{\alpha\mid \alpha \in A\; \forall\alpha\}$

Also for part (2) do I just have to write $\limsup A_{k}$ and $\liminf A_{k}$?

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: For the first question you need define the domain of $\alpha 's$..   Second question - both representations lead to empty sets.

Comment: For part one $\alpha$ $\in$ A. Can you let me know if i'm going right.

Answer (score 0):

1. The intersection of the A's is empty, the union is (0,1).  Find two A's with empty intersection.
2. The first expression is [1,2], the second is empty.  Find two A's with empty intersection.

The edit for part one is incorrect, indicates confusion.  For part two, what need is there to mention limsup and liminf?

Now that you know the answers, prove them correct or in error before giving them as answers.  Only that way you will learn the subject material.